# Dynamic array in nested for loop - ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I would know how insert an array in an if of a for loop nested in another for loop.

```
for (var q...){
for (var u...){ 
 if ("array_"+q+"["+u+"]" == "[object object1]") {
 object1 = ++object1;}
 ...
...
```

"array_"+q+"["+u+"]" can be traced for example like:

```
array_1[0], array_1[1], array_1[2], array_1[3]
array_2[0], array_2[1], array_2[2], array_2[3] etc...
```

But if I try to check if is equal to [object object1] it doesn't work.

What's wrong in the syntax below?

```
if ("array_"+q+"["+u+"]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's wrong in the syntax below?

That this: `"array_"+q+"["+u+"]"` is a string. A string is not a reference to your array, it is just... string. If you want to use something like that, you have to do it like this:

`this["array_"+q][u]; //this would be a reference! Note this would work only with dynamic objects (= MovieClips, or your class declared as dynamic)`

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider marking this question as solved (the checkbox next to the answer).